# Variables inside functions + callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I have a function (zReaderRequest, see below) where a callback function is using a variable that is local to this first function, i.e. "rq" here. Will new calls to the function zReaderRequest create a new variable "rq" or will the callback functions use the same "rq"? If they use the same, what can I do? Create an object that holds this function, or?

```
function zReaderRequest(zURL, outputElt, displayFun) {
    switch (outputElt.dataset.zReaderStatus) {
    case undefined:
        outputElt.dataset.zReaderStatus = "requested";
        var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rq.onload = function() {
            if (displayFun(rq, outputElt))
                outputElt.dataset.zReaderStatus = "received";
            else
                outputElt.dataset.zReaderStatus = "failed";
        };
        rq.open("GET", zURL, true);
        rq.setRequestHeader("Zotero-API-Version", "2");
        rq.send();
        break;
    }
}
```

Where do I learn this so I do not have to ask questions like this one? ;-)

Comment: Each time you call the function, it’ll make a new one. How can you avoid asking this type of question? Well, you can try to put together a short experiment to confirm that it works as you expect, or just trust JavaScript to not behave *too* strangely.

Comment: `switch` with one case = `if`. Best to use the correct control structure...

Comment: Thanks minitech, but it is not so easy to test. (Or, I can do it with exactly this function, but timing might be fooling me. ;-) )

Comment: Yes, but it is more future-proof this way, @T.J.Crowder... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call-back function is a closure — it references the independent variable `rq`. Every call to that call-back will use the same `rq` variable. However, if you call `zReaderRequest` another time, it will create a new closure that refers to a different object stored in a different `rq` (since `rq` comes into existence when the `zReaderRequest` function is entered). I think this is the behavior you want for that code.

As to where to learn about all this stuff, I recommend the [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) at the Mozilla Developer Network. Closures are discussed in the chapter named (surprise!) [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). Another good resource at MDN is [A re-introduction to JavaScript (JS Tutorial)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript). They cover a lot of the same material, but with different exposition.

Comment: Thanks, Ted. Very nice, then I do not have to think very much about that type of code. ;-)

Comment: @Leo - Er, you always have to think about your code (well, at least when you're coding). :)

Comment: Depends on what I am doing, @Ted. Most of the time I just want some code to do what I intended... ;-)

Comment: The re-intro was a very good start for me. I also found the "Working with objects" pleasant to read. "Closures" let me a bit doubtful. What did they say? Did this create a memory loop outside of IE too, or? etc.

Comment: @Leo - The memory loop is a problem only in IE and only when a closure is used as an event handler on a DOM element and a reference to the DOM element is in scope for the closure. Your code doesn't seem to be close to doing that.

Comment: Thanks @Ted. I do have a lot of that kind of constructs, but I actually do not care about old non-standard versions of IE. I have not got time for that. So if it only happens there I see no problem. ;-) -